# Browser return "Not found DNS record" but server has it set

Tags: domain-name-system, httpd

I have a big problem with one of domain. I bought domain and set correct dns and create domain on server via directadmin. Domain work. Yesterday browser return "Not found DNS address" and file `/var/named/xxx.xx.db` was empty so I add that content:

```
$TTL 14400 @       IN      SOA     ns230046.ovh.net.     
hostmaster.xxx.xx. (
                                                2013101503
                                                14400
                                                3600
                                                1209600
                                                86400 )

xxx.xx.    14400   IN      NS      ns230046.ovh.net. 
xxx.xx.    14400   IN      NS      sdns2.ovh.net.

*.xxx.xx.  14400   IN      A       178.33.226.191 
ftp        14400   IN      A       178.33.226.191 
localhost  14400   IN      A       127.0.0.1 
mail       14400   IN      A       178.33.226.191 
pop        14400   IN      A       178.33.226.191 
smtp       14400   IN      A       178.33.226.191 
xxx.xx.    14400   IN      A       178.33.226.191 
www        14400   IN      A       178.33.226.191

xxx.xx.    14400   IN      MX      10 mail



xxx.xx.    14400   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx ip4:178.33.226.191 ~all"

localhost       14400   IN      AAAA    ::1
```

After 24h domain still dont work with that same error, whois return correct data but page http://mxtoolbox.com/ return message "Sorry, we couldn't find any name servers for".

Anyone know what can be wrong?

Comment: Without the domain name we can't really help with these kinds of problems

Comment: The domain is uslugirandkowe.pl

Comment: Neither nameserver you listed is responding to requests for `uslugirandkowe.pl` - do you run both?

Comment: Server work as distributor. If i enter to uslugirandkowe.pl serwer check is that domain exist and if is directs to them. In this way works every domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain has two nameservers configured:

- `ns230046.ovh.net.` is functioning correctly and returning answers.
- `sdns2.ovh.net` is returning `REFUSED` for your domain.

This means that there is a 50% chance that ISP nameservers will fail their lookup when querying authoritative servers.

```
# dig @sdns2.ovh.net uslugirandkowe.pl SOA | grep status
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 45191
```

We cannot tell you why the server is returning `REFUSED`. Please make sure this nameserver is configured to respond to requests for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly be informed that the ns which you had given is resolving successfully without any issues. I have seen them on dnswatch.info,

```
 ns230046.ovh.net  A  178.33.226.191
 sdns2.ovh.net     A  213.251.188.141
```

I surely suspect there may be three major reasons that website is not working.

```
 1. Your named service is not running at your server.
 2. Your hosting for website *.xxx.xx. is removed from server, due to which your zone file is removed.
 3. If you are using above name-servers as a primary name servers for your server, then both name servers should also be assigned IP in  /var/named/xxx.xx.db. So add these entries to your zone file.

 ns230046.ovh.net IN A  178.33.226.191
 sdns2.ovh.net    IN A  213.251.188.141
```

Comment: That is only true for `ns230046.ovh.net`. `sdns2.ovh.net` is returning REFUSED.